# Ввод "Всё ли верно введено" и в случае ошибки переход для исправления

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Как сделать, чтобы после ввода данных в матрицу, программа спрашивала всё ли верно введено и в случае если нет, то предлагала выбрать в какой именно строке и дала возможность исправить эту ошибку в ней?

Я предполагал, что можно с помощью: `function TryStrToFloat(s: string; var value: single): boolean;` Однако толком с ней работать я не умею и что-то пока не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста либо какие-нибудь другие способы, либо как работать с этой функцией?

Вот часть кода в который нужно собственно "воткнуть" этот код (извиняюсь, за тавтологию):

```
writeln('Решение СЛАУ по методу Гаусса.');
 repeat
 writeln;
 writeln('Введите колич-во неизвестных величин и нажмите ENTER:');
 readln(s);{читаем строку}
 val(s,x,v);{пытаемся преобразовать ее в число, в переменную C - упадет позиция, с недопустимым символом}
 if v<>0 then
 writeln('Должно быть число')
  else
    n := Round(x);
 until v=0;
```

Comment: Сделал так чтоб спрашивала и возвращала, но использовал goto для перехода к началу цикла, а хотелось бы так, что бы пользователь мог выбрать к какому именно значению ему бы хотелось перейти, исправить его и чтоб программа продолжилась дальше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбейте свой вопрос на подзадачи.

Каждая подзадача выполняется отдельной маленькой процедурой или функцией.

Как пример, частично на псевдокоде:

```pascal
function EnterNumber: Double;
var
  s: string;
begin
  repeat
    readln(s);
    if not TryStrToFloat(s, Result) then
      writeln('Требуется число')
    else
      Break;
  until False;
end;

procedure EnterMatrixElement(Row, Col: integer);
begin
  Matrix[Row, Col]:=EnterNumber;
end;

function IsAllOk: Boolean;
begin
  // спрашиваем - все ли в порядке
  Result:= что_ответил_пользователь (да/нет)
end;

{узнавание_размерности_матрицы;}

{исходное_заполнение_матрицы}

while not IsAllOk do // пока пользователь не скажет, что всё в порядке
  begin
    Write('В какой строке неправильно?'); // узнаем координаты ошибочного ввода
    Row:=Round(EnterNumber);
    Write('В каком столбце?');
    Col:=Round(EnterNumber);
    EnterMatrixElement(Row, Col); // и меняем его содержимое.
  end;
// сюда попадем только когда пользователь скажет, что "да, всё ок".
```

Comment: что-то не получается ничего.. Чем заменить EnterMatrixElement, а то он говорит, что имя неизвестно, хотя как процедура объявлено, так же и с "Matrix" и с "EnterNumber", 1-ое я пробовал заменить переменной "a", она у меня отвечает за размерность массива и определена типом "real", но не помогает

Comment: @SergeyM Думаю,у вас проблема с неправильным синтаксисом. При нормальном написании (не надо забывать, что это не весь код приложения, а только часть - применительно к вопросу) - всё компилируется без проблем. Собственно, на ваш вопрос отвечает последняя часть кода (а именно - цикл while), приведенного мной в ответе. Всё остальное я написал исключительно для пояснения - что именно должны делать разные части программы.

Comment: а почему после вставки этой функции и процедуры(function EnterNumber: Double;) (procedure EnterMatrixElement(Row, Col: integer);) , у меня вывод ошибку, что в конце программы ожидалось не "end.", а "end;" или их не нужно вставлять? Но иначе он мне говорит, что эти имена снова таки неизвестны.. А заменять их на другие имена бесполезно, всё равно то же самое пишет

Comment: @SergeyM потому что вам нужно подтянуть знание синтаксиса языка, который вы используете. В частности - основное тело программы начинается с `begin` и заканчивается `end.` И так как ответ озвучивает **концепцию**, то этих reserved words, а равно и объявлений переменных в приведенном мной коде нет.